# Convert comma separated string of ints to int array

Tags: c#

I only found a way to do it the opposite way round: create a comma separated string from an int list or array, but not on how to convert input like `string str = "1,2,3,4,5";` to an array or list of ints.

Here is my implementation (inspired by [this post by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018407/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-get-a-set-of-items-by-index-from-a-collection/1018624#1018624)):

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> StringToIntList(string str)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var chunks = str.Split(',').AsEnumerable();

        using (var rator = chunks.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (rator.MoveNext())
            {
                int i = 0;

                if (Int32.TryParse(rator.Current, out i))
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you think this is a good approach or is there a more easy, maybe even built in way?

**EDIT:** Sorry for any confusion, but the method needs to handle invalid input like `"1,2,,,3"` or `"###, 5,"` etc. by skipping it.

Comment: You are needlessly complicating your code by not using `foreach`.  The post you're copying from is solving a _completely_ different problem.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You should use a foreach loop, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> StringToIntList(string str) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        yield break;

    foreach(var s in str.Split(',')) {
        int num;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out num))
            yield return num;
    }
}
```

Note that like your original post, this will ignore numbers that couldn't be parsed.

If you want to throw an exception if a number couldn't be parsed, you can do it much more simply using LINQ:

```
return (str ?? "").Split(',').Select<string, int>(int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 81):

If you don't want to have the current error handling behaviour, it's really easy:

```
return text.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```

Otherwise, I'd use an extra helper method [(as seen this morning!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761416/1761430#1761430):

```
public static int? TryParseInt32(string text)
{
    int value;
    return int.TryParse(text, out value) ? value : (int?) null;
}
```

and:

```
return text.Split(',').Select<string, int?>(TryParseInt32)
                      .Where(x => x.HasValue)
                      .Select(x => x.Value);
```

or if you don't want to use the method group conversion:

```
return text.Split(',').Select(t => t.TryParseInt32(t)
                      .Where(x => x.HasValue)
                      .Select(x => x.Value);
```

or in query expression form:

```
return from t in text.Split(',')
       select TryParseInt32(t) into x
       where x.HasValue
       select x.Value;
```

Comment: For a java/c# guy, your answers always seem very functional to me :=)

Comment: When it comes to LINQ, that's not entirely surprising :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the method group conversion?

Comment: Some people might prefer the lambda which has better type inference. I like to provide options :)

Comment: Yes, but then again you let it come to LINQ when you can, are you not tempted to write a book like say 'F# in depth' sometimes?

Comment: I hardly know any F# - only what I learned working with Tomas Petricek on "Functional programming for the real world" :)

Comment: @Jon: any difference between `select x into y` and `let y = x`?

Comment: @Konrad: "let" propagates the rest of the existing range variables as well. "select x into y" wipes everything but x, effectively.

Comment: about you 4th code block, isnt this easier? `.Split(',').Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)).Select(t => int.Parse(t)).ToArray()`

Comment: As a shortcut you can use `Select(int.Parse)`.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, although method group conversions changed slightly between C# 3 and C# 4. It's *possible* that that's an example where it wouldn't have worked in C# 3 but does in C# 4+... I can never remember the exact details.

Comment: .Select(x => x.Value); is it required at the end ?

Comment: @BimalDas: Yes, because otherwise the result will be an `IEnumerable<int?>` instead of an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 35):

Without using a lambda function and for valid inputs only, I think it's clearer to do this:

```
Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(value.Split(','), Convert.ToInt32);
```

Comment: i found I did not need this part `<string, int>`

Answer (score 8):

Let us assume that you will be reading the string from the console. Import System.Linq and try this one:

```
int[] input = Console.ReadLine()
            .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

This has been asked before.  .Net has a built-in ConvertAll function for converting between an array of one type to an array of another type.  You can combine this with Split to separate the string to an array of strings

Example function:

```
 static int[] ToIntArray(this string value, char separator)
 {
     return Array.ConvertAll(value.Split(separator), s=>int.Parse(s));
 }
```

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797750/is-this-the-best-way-in-c-to-convert-a-delimited-string-to-an-int-array)

Answer (score 7):

--EDIT-- It looks like I took his question heading too literally - he was asking for an array of ints rather than a List --EDIT ENDS--

Yet another helper method...

```
private static int[] StringToIntArray(string myNumbers)
{
    List<int> myIntegers = new List<int>();
    Array.ForEach(myNumbers.Split(",".ToCharArray()), s =>
    {
        int currentInt;
        if (Int32.TryParse(s, out currentInt))
            myIntegers.Add(currentInt);
    });
    return myIntegers.ToArray();
}
```

quick test code for it, too...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myNumbers = "1,2,3,4,5";
    int[] myArray = StringToIntArray(myNumbers);
    Console.WriteLine(myArray.Sum().ToString()); // sum is 15.

    myNumbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,bad";
    myArray = StringToIntArray(myNumbers);
    Console.WriteLine(myArray.Sum().ToString()); // sum is 21

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for longs, but you can modify it easily to work with ints.

```
private static long[] ConvertStringArrayToLongArray(string str)
{
    return str.Split(",".ToCharArray()).Select(x => long.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This will throw on unparsable numbers; he appears to want to skip them.

Comment: This does not do the same thing.  His version handles non-integers gracefully by skipping them.

Comment: Good point, but I was going by the input example he provided:
string str = "1,2,3,4,5"

Comment: This won't work at all; you forgot to call `Split`.  This will enumerate over each _character_ in the string, and will throw on the `,`.

Comment: oops, you're right. Sorry, I've corrected it. But this only works for valid inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why taking out the enumerator explicitly offers you any advantage over using a `foreach`.  There's also no need to call `AsEnumerable` on `chunks`.