# Taking string Input and making a int array

Tags: c#

How do I take an string input and make it into an int array?

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int numb = Convert.Toint32(input);          
int[] intArray = // what do i write here to make it take the "input" length, and put the input into an int array?
```

Comment: Can you give example of input string and what the output should be for that string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string of ints to int array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763613/convert-comma-separated-string-of-ints-to-int-array)

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much detail, but if the input is a comma-delimited list of numbers you could do:

```
string input = "1,2, 3,4  ,5 ,6";  // string to simulate input
int[] numbers = input.Split(new char[] {','})
                     .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                     .ToArray();
```

this will obviously blow up if any string between commas is not a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array from a string in two different ways.

You can either use the split method, which breaks the string into an array of substrings - and then you'd have to parse each element of this array. This is probably what you want, since it seems you want an array of integers;

Or you can convert the string to a byte array. [Means to do so have been discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp). Then you convert those values to integers as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int numb = Convert.ToInt32(input);
int[] intArray = new int[numb];
for (int i; i < intArray.length; i++)
{
   intArray[i] = numb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For obtaining the length of the input you can do the following:

```
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int numb = input.Length;
    int[] intArray = new int[1];
    intArray[0] = numb;
```