# How to remove comma from string and add each word to collection in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to remove the comma from the following string:

```
string mystring = "One,Two,Three,Four";
```

and add each word in collection
something like that  One,Two,Three,Four

I want this

```
 NewsTag tag1 = new NewsTag();
 tag1.Name = "one";

 NewsTag tag2 = new NewsTag();
 tag2.Name = "three";

NewsTag tag3 = new NewsTag();
tag3.Name = "three";
```

Thank you

Comment: There are no commas in your example. Please edit your post to be more specific, it's entirely unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: string mystring = "One,Two,Three,Four";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string of ints to int array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763613/convert-comma-separated-string-of-ints-to-int-array)

Comment: look up the how to use `string.Replace()` also look at `List<string>` and how to add / iterate values and add to a Generic Collection this is what `GOOGLE` is there for..

Comment: @Lucia if you understand what I have coded this will do exactly what you need

Comment: This should be enough: `mystring.Split(',').Select(name => new NewsTag { Name = name }).Tolist()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
List<NewsTag> list = new List<NewsTag>();
    list.Add(new NewsTag());
    list.Add(NewsTag);
    list.Add(NewsTag);
    list.Add(NewsTag);

    List<string> names = "One,Two,Three,Four".Split(',').ToList<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++) {
    list[i].Name = names[i];
}
```

Comment: @Lucia Try `var list = mystring.Split(',').Select(n => new NewsTag { Name = n, }).ToList();`.