# c# Convert String Format Not Value to bytes

Tags: c#, byte

this sound a bit confusing to me,  but i was wondering how to convert a string type to a bytes the `string format` is same as `bytes` example :

```
String Buffer = "31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,236,189,9,156,212"; // its bytes on string Format
```

i want to convert that string to bytes (**Not Converting the Value of the string but the actual type)

**Edit :** 
example of what i want exactly :

```
`string = "10,156,0,0,4,0,236,156";`
```

to be

`byte[] buffer = {10,156,0,0,4,0,236,156};`

Comment: I'm afraid this sounds confusing not only to you...

Comment: I thought so :(

Comment: So split on comma and parse the result as bytes?

Comment: please give a more detailed explanation of what you're after if you want useful answers

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763613/convert-comma-separated-string-of-ints-to-int-array), replace int with byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for size:

```
var bytes = Buffer.Split(',').Select(Byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

This splits your string into an array of strings (separated by `,`), then parses them to bytes and converts to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
 var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("your string");
```

Ok, value

```
"31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,236,189,9,156,212"
.Split(",".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(x=>Byte.Parse(x)).ToArray()
```

Code above splits your string (by ',') into several stirngs ("31", "139", ... , "212"), then remove empty entries (if any), and that trying to parse each string to byte. At the result you will get array of bytes.

Comment: @jeroenh I answered on question in that way, as I understand it.