# I can not output my answer as a multiple number it said specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#

I can not output my answer as a multiple number it said specified cast is not valid

This is the code:

```
using System;

namespace Practice
{
    class MainClass
    {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Console.Write("What is your min varible: ");
        int min_variable = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("WHat is your max variable: ");
        int max_variable = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine($"This is your range {min_variable} to {max_variable}");

        Console.Write("Please enter your all number: ");
        int[] numebral = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Split(',')) };
        Console.WriteLine($"This is your number: {numebral}");

      }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I expect [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60745686/3181933) is what you need. Just substitute its `int[] input` for your `int[] numebral`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763626/3181933) is better though because it uses `int.TryParse` and ignores non-integer values. You can use it like `int[] numebral = StringToIntList(Console.ReadLine()).ToArray();`

Comment: The answers certainly should help but they probably do not explain the reasoning for this issue in a way for OP to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert an array into an int. This is how String.split works:

```
string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string[] words = phrase.Split(' ');

foreach (var word in words)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"<{word}>");
}
```

So instead, you need to convert each single string in the array into int.